# Duplication float values when using structs in a function

Tags: c, function, struct, scope, function-definition

I have this program to calculate the midpoint given two points. It takes in the coordinates of two points and return the coordinates of their midpoint.

Somewhere along the way, my program started to output wrong answers. I checked it and found out the faulty part was with the function. I have no idea why this happens.

Attached is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct line{
    struct point{
        float x;
        float y;
    }point1, point2, midpoint;
};

struct line solveMidpoint(struct line line1){
    printf("%f\n", line1.point1.x);
    line1.midpoint.x = (line1.point1.x+line1.point2.x)/2;
    line1.midpoint.y = (line1.point1.y+line1.point2.y)/2;
    return line1;
}

int main(void){
    struct line liner;
    printf("Enter x and y for point1: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &(liner.point1.x), &(liner.point1.y));
    printf("Enter x and y for point2: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &(liner.point2.x), &(liner.point2.x));
    printf("Midpoint: %f, %f", solveMidpoint(liner).midpoint.x, solveMidpoint(liner).midpoint.y);
}
```

When I input two points, it then results to this:

```
Enter x and y for point1: 1 1
Enter x and y for point2: 0 1
1.000000
1.000000
Midpoint: 1.000000, 0.500000
[Program finished]
```

The program just printed the float twice. I've made a similar program but the issue doesn't occur in it. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I've noticed the replies regarding the undefined behavior with the array and fixed it. However, my main issue is with the printf statement printing two instances of the value instead of one.

I still don't know why calling line1.point1.x results to its value being printed twice. Calling it inside the main function prints only once.

Comment: You called `solveMidpoint` twice on the last line of your `main` function, and each call printed one line.

Comment: The function `solveMidpoint` also printes a value.

Comment: You MUST NOT rely on returning a pointer to a function-local variable. That variable does not exist when the function returns. I refer to `float arr[2];`

Comment: Why isn't the mid-point represented by a `struct point` too?

Answer (score 1):

```
line1.midpoint = &arr[0];
```

You're bringing out a pointer to a local variable from within your function, when that function ends the array is no longer available. Welcome to undefined behavior territory.

Answer (score 1):

Within the function `solveMidpoint` you output the same value

```
printf("%f\n", line1.point1.x);
```

But returning a pointer to a local array that will not be alive after exiting the function invokes undefined behavior

```
float *solveMidpoint(struct line line1){
    float arr[2];
    //...
    line1.midpoint = &arr[0];
    return line1.midpoint;
}
```

And moreover it seems in this statement

```
printf("Midpoint: %f, %f", *solveMidpoint(liner), *solveMidpoint(liner)+1);
```

you mean the following arguments

```
printf("Midpoint: %f, %f", *solveMidpoint(liner), *( solveMidpoint(liner)+1 ));
```

However there is no reason to declare the pointer within the structure and to return a pointer from the function. You could just return an object of the type float or of a structure type that contains two data members of the type float..

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
printf("Enter x and y for point2: ");
scanf("%f %f", &(liner.point2.x), &(liner.point2.x));
```

the x and y for point2 would not have `.x` field for both inputs.  Suggest:

```
printf("Enter x and y for point2: ");
scanf("%f %f", &(liner.point2.x), &(liner.point2.y));
                                                 ^ 
                                                 ^
```